# using JDirectoryChooser in java swing

Tags: java, swing

I need a simple example of using `JDirectoryChooser` in java swing please.

`JDirectoryChooser chooser = new JDirectoryChooser();` always gives me a compile time error that `JDirectoryChooser cannot be resolved`. I think it must be a library problem but I am not quite sure which library it needs?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

`JDirectoryChooser` is not part of the official JDK and seems to be part of JAlbum. But looking at the [javadoc](http://jalbum.net/api/se/datadosen/component/JDirectoryChooser.html), you can achieve the same result by using a regular `JFileChooser`

Comment: This saved me a wtf there's a JDirectoryChooser and a trip to google!

Comment: @Thihara my first reaction was a WTF, do I remember the name of `JFileChooser` wrong ? Then I used google to ease my mind

Comment: Same here I was like WTF I never knew this new thing.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "JDirectoryChooser," but `JFileChooser` has the following method:

`setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);`

Comment: See answer by Robin. Always add referrence. This is more like a comment as well.